# Empty Collection using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, datacontractserializer

I have a `Restaurant` object, which contains a `Menu`.  The `Menu` contains `MenuItems`.

Via the Entity Framework Code First, I created a database and stored a single `Restaurant` in it, which has a single `MenuItem`.  I've checked the database, and the `MenuItem` is there.  However, it isn't getting loaded when I retrieve the `Restaurant` object.

I tried implementing the `[OnSerializing]` attribute for the `Menu` object (since this is taking place in a WCF application), so as to "force" the `MenuItems` to be loaded, but that didn't have any effect.  I've also seen folks recommending the `[IncludeAttribute]`, but that attribute exists in two assemblies, neither of which is present on my machine as far as I can tell.

I've attempted to turn on logging/tracing for the Entity framework, but so far without success.

Anyway, here is how I've got my data objects defined:

```
[DataContract]
public class MenuItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract]
public class ListOfMenuItem : List<MenuItem>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class Menu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Alternate constructor, used during serialization operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pContext"></param>
    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext pContext)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public Menu()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        MenuItems = new ListOfMenuItem();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ListOfMenuItem MenuItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Restaurant
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Alternate constructor, used during serialization operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pContext"></param>
    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext pContext)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public Restaurant()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Hours = new HoursOfOperation();
        Menu = new Menu();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unique name and identifier for a restaurant.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Key]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What hours is the restaurant open.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public HoursOfOperation Hours
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What does the restaurant have to eat and drink.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public Menu Menu
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And the database context is defined as:

```
public class RestaurantDirectory : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned `OnSerializing` but your code contains only `OnDeserializing`.

Comment: Because the OnSerializing method didn't help, I pulled it back out, just to avoid polluting the code with stuff that didn't really do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework 4.1 on WCF, put this in your DbContext constructor

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

If you are using 4.0, use `ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Code first for EF 
Typically you will mark your collection of items as virtual.

Example

---

```
public class MenuContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet Menues{ get; set; }
    public DbSet MenuItems { get; set; }
}
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MenuID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MenuItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I wind up getting an exception on the *service* side:  Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Restaurant_3D8895CC957DE866A15042FB47041B9ECC35036A92C4E63315C1E89A5B629224' with data contract name 'Restaurant_3D8895CC957DE866A15042FB47041B9ECC35036A92C4E63315C1E89A5B629224' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver....  I'm not sure why the name of the class is decorated with that long string of characters, which appears to be just because I added the virtual keyword to a few key spots.